# Laravel 5 route issue -> display data on view

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have a route problem in laravel 5. I would like to make a system that allows me to create routes with a variable. I have already searched, but I find nothing that works for me.
I want to put a variable in the url so that when I click on my button it shows me in the url: ... / $ range / $ sub-range / $ product_name
Example: ... / beauty / hygiene / moisturizing cream.
Thank you for your help

**Update 1**

@JeffreyWesterkamp Yes I made the route like that : `Route::get('/{name}', 'RangeController@getRange')->name('range');` , and in my controller :

```html
public function getRange($name)
    {
 $ranges=Range::all();
  $aRange=Range::find($name);
 return view('guest/range/index')->with('aRange', $aRange)->with('ranges',$ranges)->with('name',$name);
    }
```

I have two view used in this cases. layoutguest.blade.php and index.blade.php in a folder (guest/range/).
In my view layoutguest, I made this :

```
@foreach ($ranges as $range)
                        <li>

                            <a href="{{route('range',$range->name)}}">{{$range->name}}</a>

                        </li>
                       @endforeach
```

And on the side of the index.blade.php. I made

```
@foreach ($ranges as $gamme)
@extends('layoutguest')
@section('content')

@foreach ($ranges as $gamme)
<section ...>
<div ....>
 <h4>{{$range->name}}</h4>

    <p>
         {{$range->description}}
    </p>
</div>
.......
</section>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

For now, when I click on the menu(range) in layoutguest. It displays in the url : domaine/public/nameofrange
So that is good. but I have a problem with `@foreach` on index.blade, It displays the name and description of all ranges. While I would like it to display the name and description on the active menu, not all ranges.
The `@foreach` on layoutguest work good !
Many thanks in advance for your assistance, and I am looking forward to hearing from you.

**Update 2**

If I replace `$name` by `$id`. I have what I want in layoutguest.blade and index.blade. But the url display 'public/1'.
I take off the `@foreach` of the index.blade and add `{{$aRange->name}}

I want to know how to have in my url and in my page the information of the range, like in url "domaine/public/nameofgamme" and on the index.blade "name and description by range" Thanks you for your help

Comment: how about route parameters? You can define route segments as variable by   using curly braces in your route definition: `/some-static-segment/{variable_1}/{variable_2}`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp can you help me please? I'm stuck with this problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to **update 2**

In your `controller` you do `$aRange = Range::find($name)`:

```php
public function getRange($name)
{
    $ranges = Range::all();
    $aRange = Range::find($name);
    return view('guest/range/index')->with('aRange', $aRange)->with('ranges',$ranges)->with('name',$name);
}
```

The `find` method however always searches by **primary index**. we could change this line to allow us to retrieve the range record **where** the name corresponds to your variable's value, as follows:

```php
public function getRange($name)
{
    $ranges = Range::all();
    // Use where() here to search by anything else than primary index
    $aRange = Range::where('name', $name)->first();

    return view('guest/range/index')->with('aRange', $aRange)->with('ranges',$ranges)->with('name',$name);
}
```

This essentially tells your database: **Look for all records `where` the name is `$name`, and when you're done searching, give me the `first` record, instead of all.**

Just for the sake of it, you could also reformat your view() call by passing your view parameters as array, instead of a separate `with()` call for each variable:

```
return view('guest/range/index', [
    'aRange' => $aRange,
    'ranges' => $ranges,
    'name'   => $name
]);
```

... and because the variable names are the same as the names for your view, this can be even shorter with the `compact()` function:

```
return view('guest/range/index', compact(
    'aRange',
    'ranges',
    'name'
]);
```